# Convert .pages to .pdf with images as a preview (or convert vectorized images to lossy formats within .pdf)

Tags: pdf, preview, pages, iwork, file-conversion

I have a long paper in which all of the pictures I drew and put them in the document as .pdf.

Is there a way to protect these images from copying by conversion to image formats such as (.jpeg, .png, etc.), i.e. lossy formats? When I make presentation in Keynote, there is an option to "print all images as a preview", which converts them all in such way. Is there something like that in Pages or can I somehow convert these image after I export the .pages file as a .pdf?

Please note, that I don't want to convert the whole .pdf to image as I would like the text to remain vectorized for better readability as the footnotes are written with small-sized font.

Comment: What do you mean by "protect", against what do you want to protect?

Comment: @nohillside If the pictures are all vectorized, someone can easily use them as a "template". This paper is still in a working stage before release and I don't not want to manually convert them all to image formats and replace them one by one.

Comment: Can‘t you export them as jpg from wherever you draw them?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, but as I mentioned, I would prefer to do this in .pdf instead of replacing them all. And since for example Keynote does that, I begin to wonder whether there is something I can in this case.